# Android studio Kotlin multiple buttons to open multiple activity

Tags: android, kotlin, button

I have 5 buttons. I got one to work but i can't make the other 4 work. Here is my code for the first button:

```
//MainActivity.kt
fun next(view: View){
        val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

Then i just put a onclick on my first button.

```
//fragment_dashboard.xml
android:onClick="next"
```

Im expecting the other 4 buttons to open a specific activity like button1 will open the activity "Chapter I". I've been trying to use multiple intents but it doesn't work as well. Any suggestions on how i can make onClick listeners for the other buttons?

Here is the fragment_dashboard.xml where i've put the 5 buttons:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="fragments.DashboardFragment">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="148dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="149dp"
        android:text="Chapter I"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:onClick="next" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="146dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="146dp"
        android:text="Chapter II"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="143dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="144dp"
        android:text="Chapter III"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="143dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="144dp"
        android:text="Chapter IV"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="146dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="146dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="208dp"
        android:text="Chapter V"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button4" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

!UPDATE!
I tried another method to set onclick for my buttons. It doesn't show any error but everytime I run my app it keeps crashing the moment i run it.

```
val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
        button.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(this, ChapterIAct::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        val button2 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button2)
        button2.setOnClickListener {
            val intent1 = Intent(this, ChapterIIAct::class.java)
            startActivity(intent1)
        }

        val button3 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button3)
        button3.setOnClickListener {
            val intent2 = Intent(this, ChapterIIIAct::class.java)
            startActivity(intent2)
        }
val button4 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button4)
        button4.setOnClickListener{
            val intent3 = Intent(this, ChapterIVAct::class.java)
            startActivity(intent3)
        }

        val button5 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button5)
        button5.setOnClickListener{
            val intent4 = Intent(this, ChapterVAct::class.java)
            startActivity(intent4)
        }
```

[Button onClicks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYKYV.png)

!UPDATE!
I put my onclick inside the onCreateView inside the fragment.

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false)
        val button = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
        button.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(this, ChapterIAct::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        return view
    }
```

but the Intent has an error of "None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
(Context!, Class<*>!) defined in android.content.Intent
(String!, Uri!) defined in android.content.Intent"

[Intent error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwvZC.png)

Comment: you should post the did-not-work part, not the worked one

Comment: 1) Post the code, 2) What does "can't make work" means exactly? Provide details like "I'm expecting the button to do this when I click on it but it does this other thing instead". 3) If any error, post the full stacktrace.

Comment: Post the whole layout

Comment: anything else i should put?

Comment: You need to add "android:onClick=" "  attribute to other button in xml file and also call related function in activity class

Comment: i tried a different method. but it keeps crashing even though there are no errors. see the update

Comment: Can you share the logcat, where is the error coming from

Comment: there is no error. it just crashes without any signs.

Comment: ok share us, method `onCreate` . @Itsuki

Comment: i posted to code and image at the most bottom part of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed that these buttons all inside the fragment. You are suppose to do like this.

Inside the `onCreateView` function

```
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false)
    val button = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button) //add view
    button.setOnClickListener{
        val intent = Intent(context, ChapterIAct::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
    //all here same like at top
    return view
```

Comment: sorry im new at this. How do i make the onCreateView function?

Comment: @Itsuki just press anywhere inside the fragment, type `onCreateView` and then it will show up suggestion

Comment: ok i found it. but for some reason the Intent has and error "None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied."

Comment: intent = "Intent"(this, ChaperIAct::class.java)

Comment: the Intent inside the quotation has an error

Comment: check the image i uploaded "Intent error"

Comment: @Itsuki I updated the answer. replace `this` to `context`

Comment: 1 more. how do i do it for the other buttons?

Comment: @Itsuki same like this one. need to view.find... and change to context

Comment: @Itsuki I have added comment in my answer.